# Getting binding expression out of a DataGridTemplateColumn's CellTemplate in code-behind

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, code-behind, datagridtemplatecolumn

I'm looking for a possibility to read the binding expression out of a DataGridTemplateColumn's CellTemplate in code behind.
My template columns look like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="..." Header="...">
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=City}" Style="..."/>
  </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ComboBox ... />
  </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>

</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Now I want to get the value of the binding path in the datatemplate. In this case, I'like to get the value "City".

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at this post. I hope it'll be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974420/wpf-binding-where-a-property-contains-the-path-to-the-value

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to reach the TextBlock inside the CellTemplate.

Actually @blindmeis' answer is giving a clue but I'll try to explain with different approach in a sample.

In code behind, for instance, you try to reach the object that TextBlock on MouseDoubleClick event.

You can reach TextBlock object using e.OriginalSource;

Then, BindingOperations.GetBinding(.. , ..).Path.Path will give you what are you looking for...

```
var tb = (e.OriginalSource as TextBlock);
if (tb == null)
    return;
```

After that you can use first way or second way:

First way (Attention. There is a question mark before first Path expression) :

```
var bindingPath = BindingOperations.GetBinding(tb, TextBlock.TextProperty)?.Path.Path;
```

Second way:

```
var binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(tb, TextBlock.TextProperty);
if (binding == null)
    return;

var bindingPath = binding.Path.Path;
```

Answer (score 0):

it would be good to know what you wanna do with the path value.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298274/c-wpf-get-binding-path-of-an-element-in-a-datatemplate) is an answer to a similar question.

EDIT:
thats nice i wrote an excel converter a while back :) but my version does not support Binding dot notation and TemplateColumns. the problem with TemplateColumns is that you dont know if the have 1 or more binding and how the visual tree look like. maybe in a first step you can walk down the visual tree of your template column to the first binding and take it.

Comment: Hi blindmeis, I am writing an excel export for DataGrids, and I'm using the bound values for that, but I have trouble getting out the values for all of my template columns.

Comment: for normal columns, I'm getting the values with:
if (gridColumn is DataGridBoundColumn)
{
Binding binding = ((DataGridBoundColumn)gridColumn).Binding as Binding;
}